# Correctly perform the DELETE with RestSharp

Tags: restsharp

Till now I've used RestSharp to perform POST/GET passing a JSON payload as parameter/body.
Now I've to perform a delete (you can see the example form documentation just here)

```
DELETE https://api.xxx.it/shipment
HTTP/1.1 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
X-API-KEY: APIKEY123456789
Content-Length: 10 Host: api.xxx.it 
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5) 

id=1234567
```

and my code below.

```
 public Task PerformShipmentDeleteAsync(ShipmentDeleteRequest objectRequest)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(settingsService.Endpoint);

            var request = new RestRequest("shipment", DataFormat.Json);
            request.AddHeader(Constants.XApiKey, settingsService.ApiXKey);
            request.AddParameter( "text/plain",$"id={objectRequest.Id}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var res = client.Delete(request);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

and `ShipmentDeleteRequest.cs`

```
public class ShipmentDeleteRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public  int Id { get;set; }
    }
```

The only way I've found is to format the string in this way, but It's a hack.
How do I correctly pass the body as the example without passing a string but just the C# object?

Comment: Have you tried using `AddObject`?

Comment: no, I've not... Ill try tomorrow, monday at least

Comment: Excuse me , I've tried the AddObject, but the Id is not passed...I mean somehow I need to tell the code that the property need to be called id ... if it was json I can pass the JSonProperty, here what have I to pass? [DataMember]?